# Anime without background music?

Tags: music

I now it's kinda unusual but,Is there a simple way to watch anime without background music or is there an anime without background music?

Comment: it might be possible on home releases but it would depend on if the DVD/Bluray player can disable audio tracks (like how it can switch between English and Japanese Dubs) and if the release did separate the audio track on the disk (i know some of my Dad's DVDs have a separate track for when he mutes everything but voices)

Comment: Some people watch anime completely muted but with subs, maybe that would work for you akhi